# Android AES (with Keystore) produces different cipher text with same plain text

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, android-keystore

I'm trying to make the Keystore help me generate a key for AES encryption, and use it to encrypt the plain text I put in. So here are my codes. I call the createKey() method only once in the onCreate() method of another activity, and then call the printCipherText() method many times with the same keyAlias and same plaintext. The strange thing is: every time I call the printCipherText() method, I get a different result. I'm using the same key alias and same plaintext, but why do I get different cipher text each time?

```
public class KeyCreatorClass {

    KeyStore keyStore;
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
    Cipher cipher;

    public void createKey(String keyAlias) { //I call this method only once in the onCreate() method of another activity, with keyAlias "A"
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            keyStore.load(null);
            keyGenerator.init(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyAlias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                        .build());
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String printCipherText(String keyAlias, String plainText){ //I call this method many times with the same keyAlias "A" and same plaintext in the same activity
        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return byteToHex(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "BUG";
    }

    private String byteToHex(byte[] byteArray){
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : byteArray)
            buf.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        String hexStr = buf.toString();
        return hexStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: On all these occasions, do you get the original text back when you decrypt?

Comment: Thank u I think @Artjom B. just solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using CBC mode which uses an initialization vector (IV). Since you're not specifying the IV in your code, it will be randomly generated every time the code is called. This is an important property in order to prevent an observer of ciphertexts to determine whether there is a message you've sent again. This is necessary to achieve semantic security.

Since the IV is randomly generated, you need the same IV that was used during encryption also during decryption. The IV doesn't have to be secret, but it needs to be unpredictable (which it is). One common way is to write it in front of the ciphertext and read it back during decryption. It has always the same length which is the block size. That size is 16 byte for AES.

Comment: Thank you so much! BTW, can you give an example of the "common way" of using the IV?

Comment: In your case a simple `return byteToHex(cipher.getIV()) + byteToHex(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()));` should work with the other way around using substring during decryption. If you want your encryption to work for large data, then you should use streams.